# How to fix 'py' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, path

[image]

I try to write 'py' instead of 'python', I'm getting an error. And this is my path:
[image]

Comment: Does running `doskey py = python` in command line solve the problem?

Comment: I'm getttin an error like this  'doskey' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Add `C:\Windows\System32;` to the **PATH** variable and then try running the command again. You can follow the steps [here](https://superuser.com/questions/988311/doskey-is-not-recognized-when-using-cmder) to edit PATH in more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run in the command line:

`doskey py = python`

This creates an alias for the `python` command and then you can use `py` to start the python interpreter.

If you get an error regarding `doskey` not being recognized as an internal or external command, add `C:\Windows\System32;` to the **PATH** and run the command again. You can follow the more detailed instructions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/988311/doskey-is-not-recognized-when-using-cmder) to modify the **PATH**.

Comment: This is the wrong way to solve the problem. There is no particularly good reason to alias `py` to `python` arbitrarily; people who write `py` (or suggest to do it) are doing so in order to use the Python Launcher for Windows, **not** to start a Python executable directly. If `py` isn't found, it can only realistically be because it **wasn't installed** - because it is designed to install directly into the Windows folder.